# Error after setting a bool to true

Tags: c#

I want to change the bool value of player 1 to true and since I'm not that very good with programming (a noob with other word) I would like to know how to do it and please keep it simple and explain.

so this is the code for player class

```
class Player
{
    private string name;
    private int points;
    private bool skip;

public Player(string name, int points, bool skip)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.points = points;
    this.skip = skip;
}

public string getName()
{
    return name;
}

public bool Skip
{
    get { return skip; }
    set { skip = value; }
}
}
```

At the main program I write this to change the value of skip to true

```
s1.Skip == true;
```

but I keep getting the error saying "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"

can anyone please explain what it's that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `s1.Skip = true;` and not == .

Comment: This has 3 upvotes? Literally googling `Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement` finds multiple answers (on SO, btw) that answer this. -1, marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`==` is an operator that **compares** two values for equality, while you need `=` - an assignment operator that assigns value on the right to the variable (or property, in your case) on the left:

```
s1.Skip = true;
```

You might find [this part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173142.aspx) of the C# programming guide useful.

Answer (score 2):

The `==` operator is the *equality* operator.  It returns a boolean value indicating whether or not the two operands are the same.  You want the *assignment* operator, which is `=`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using double equal signs '=='. If you want to set an variable, just use 1 equal sign. (==) is comparing variables and actually returning a bool variable.

Solution:

```
s1.Skip = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

you are using == operator, its used to compare 2 values, 
just change your operator == to =.

```
        Player p = new Player("test", 10, true);
        p.Skip = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You problem is `==`.use:

```
s1.Skip = true
```